# cross compile opencv for porting to TI DM6446

Tags: gcc, opencv, cross-compiling

I have set up target fs on

```
/home/myself/filesys/bin..etc//
```

GCC
compile:

```
host $ arm_v5t_le-gcc hello.c -o hello
```

run:

```
target $ cd /opt/hello
target $./hello
```

I have installed opencv2.3 on host ubuntu machine now I want opencv to be ported to DM6446
so i follow

1. `uncompress opencv2.3 tarball`
2. `sudo cmake OpenCV-2.3.1`
3. `sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm_v5t_le-`

but when I run the sample test from bin it runs on x86 machine which was made for ARM
I think I am not following the correct procedure to make opencv.

Is there anything I have to do to make opencv for ARM architecture,
what are the steps to follow in cross compiling?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd command you executed should provide a clue as to whether you are cross-compiling or not. If you look closely it would have shown that it was building for the i686 and not for the ARM platform.

[This blog discusses how to Cross Compile using cmake.](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling)
cmake uses different environment variables from standard make (so don't use ARCH, and CROSS-COMPILE).

Comment: thanks i saw it but was not so sure about cmakes use so i posted a question, afterwards i founded that i was not configuring cmake properly so after some search i found a tool cmake-gui which made it easy, but now the library which i have created works properly when the  .cpp code do not use highgui.h dependent function. it gives error  'undefined reference ' mostly on image functions